# Binary quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $q(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ is a binary quadratic form. And $q(x,y)>0$ for any $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$. How to prove that $\exists C>0$ such that $q(x,y)>C(x^2+y^2)$

Comment: I am assuming that $C$ is a constant?

Comment: @BanachTarski. Yes!

Comment: Let $C' = \frac{q(x,y)}{x^2 + y^2} > 0$. Since $C' > 0 \implies \exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $0 < \epsilon < C'$. If $C = \epsilon$, then $C(x^2 + y^2) < q(x,y)$

Comment: @BanachTarski, So what?

Comment: $\epsilon(x^2 + y^2) < C'(x^2 + y^2) = q(x,y)$

Comment: Your $C'$ is not constant! it's some function depending on $x,y$. I think that you are wrong

Comment: There is always some $\epsilon > 0$ for all values the function $q(x,y)$ can take so we can let $C$ be the minimum such $\epsilon$

Comment: @BanachTarski, Why? Can you show a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$q$ is continuous and non-zero on the *compact* set 
$\{ (x, y) : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$, therefore
$$
 m :=  \min \{ q(x, y) : x^2 + y^2  = 1 \}
$$
is strictly positive.

Now for arbitrary $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$,
$$
 (u, v) := (\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}})
$$
satisfies $u^2 + v^2 = 1$, and therefore
$$
 \frac{q(x, y)}{x^2 + y^2} = q( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}) = q(u, v) \ge m \, .
$$

It follows that for any $0 < C < m$,
$$
 q(x, y) >  C (x^2 + y^2) \quad \text{ for } (x, y) \ne (0, 0) \, .
$$
Of course the strict inequality cannot hold for $(x, y) = (0, 0)$.

Comment: Nice proof! Thanks! +1

Answer (score 2):

Recall that a binary quadratic form $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ is positive definite if and only if all leading principal minors of the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & \frac{b}{2} \\ \frac{b}{2} & c \end{bmatrix}$ are positive. In this case this means that $a > 0$ and $\det(A) > 0$.

Now rephrasing your question, you are asking whether there is a $d > 0$ such that $(a - d)x^2 + bxy + (c - d)y^2$ is still a positive definite quadratic form.

But since $\det(A) > 0$ the function $d \mapsto \det(A - d \cdot Id)$ (which is continuous in $d$, as it is in fact a polynomial) is positive in some interval around zero. Choose $0 < d' < a$ in said interval. Then $A - d' \cdot Id$ is a positive definite matrix, and you have found a $d' > 0$ such that $q(x, y) > d'(x^2 + y^2)$.

Comment: Your approach would even allow to compute the bound explicitly (as the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix $A$).